# HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler volatile field

Tags: netty

As far as I understood all methods within ChannelHandler classes are executed by the same thread. Correct me If I'm wrong.

What is the point to declare field volatile in that example?

private volatile Channel outboundChannel;

http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.html

Comment: I don't think it's needed, indeed. You could send a pull-request with that modification.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the examples. It is not needed. Let me fix it.